# extract and filter values from string list python

Tags: python, string

so I have an array that looks like the one below. the "error" substring always starts with this character a special character `"‘"` so I was able to just get the errors with something like this

```
a = [' 276ARDUINO_i2c.c:70:27: error: ‘ARDUINO_I2C_nI2C', ' 248rpy_i2c.h:76:40: error: ‘RPY_I2C_BASE_ADDR_LIST', ' 452rpy_i2c.c:79:77: error: ‘RPY_I2C_IRQ_LIST']
newlist = [x.split('‘')[1] for x in a]
print(newlist)
```

and the output would look like this

```
['ARDUINO_I2C_nI2C', 'RPY_I2C_BASE_ADDR_LIST', 'RPY_I2C_IRQ_LIST']
```

but now, i also need to get the name of the file related to that error. The name of the file always start with a numeric substring that I also need to remove. the output I want would look like this

```
   ['ARDUINO_i2c.c', 'ARDUINO_I2C_nI2C'], ['rpy_i2c.h', 'RPY_I2C_BASE_ADDR_LIST'], ['rpy_i2c.c','RPY_I2C_IRQ_LIST']
```

I'll apreciate any suggestions. thanks.

Comment: Why can't you use similar logic to split out the file name? The file name is preceded by numbers, and followed by a colon. Don't try and shove everything into a list comprehension, first make a regular loop. Later, you can try and condense it down to a list comprehension if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [regular expression](https://www.regular-expressions.info/) to capture the required parts of your string. For example, the following regex ([Try it online](https://regex101.com/r/13BaIa/1)):

```
\d+([^:]+):.*‘(.*)$

Explanation:
-----------
\d+                     : One or more numbers
   (     )    (  )      : Capturing groups
    [^:]+               : One or more non-colon characters (in capturing group 1)
          :             : One colon
           .*           : Any number of any character
             ‘          : The ‘ character
               .*       : Any number of any character (in capturing group 2)
                  $     : End of string
```

To use it:

```
import re

regex = re.compile(r"\d+([^:]+):.*‘(.*)$")

newlist = [regex.search(s).groups() for s in a]
```

which gives a list of tuples:

```
[('ARDUINO_i2c.c', 'ARDUINO_I2C_nI2C'),
 ('rpy_i2c.h', 'RPY_I2C_BASE_ADDR_LIST'),
 ('rpy_i2c.c', 'RPY_I2C_IRQ_LIST')]
```

If you *really* want a list of lists, you can convert the result of `.groups()` to a list:

```
newlist = [list(regex.search(s).groups()) for s in a]
```

Comment: sweet, I'm still a noob in python. I was just looking into that that re library. I really appreciate the explanation.

Comment: @pekoms you can find more information about regular expressions here: https://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 0):

I have created this code to get the exact result as you like but there could be more efficient ways too. I have split the values and used regex to get the needed result.

```
import re
a = [' 276ARDUINO_i2c.c:70:27: error: ‘ARDUINO_I2C_nI2C', '248rpy_i2c.h:76:40: error: ‘RPY_I2C_BASE_ADDR_LIST', ' 452rpy_i2c.c:79:77: error: ‘RPY_I2C_IRQ_LIST']
r=[]
for x in a:
    d=x.split(": error: ‘")
    r.append([re.sub("[0-9]{3}","",d[0].split(":")[0].strip()),d[1]])
print(r)
```

Comment: You haven't used regex

Comment: @PranavHosangadi yes I did mistake, I m fixing it. Thank you.

Comment: You can do `"[0-9]{3}"` or `r"\d{3}"` to match three digits, no need to multiply the string three times

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I don't know about regex much, I just learnt a little. I will consider your suggestion.